# How do I calculate the input voltage based on an ADC reading?

Tags: adc, analog, measurement, voltage-measurement

[image: Excerpt from the schematic]

+UB is a 12V power supply. I have to find the voltage on U_KL30.

I take this U_KL30 as an input at `PortA<1>` of my [MC9S08DZ60](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC9S08DZ60.pdf) and use an ADC to get a digital value. Now I need an equation to reverse engineer the digital value received from the ADC to the actual voltage on U_KL30. What equation can I use?

Comment: I sat down to break my head further with the diagram, and came up with this:
V_KL30 = UB*(R19/(R19+R18)).
Am i atleast in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, that's a start, but it ignores the effects of the capacitor and diodes.

Comment: ...which may or may not be important depending on the type of signal applied.  In words, there will be a degree of low pass filtering, and some protecting clamping voltage limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. That the uC has a fully calibrated ADC with precision circuits and temperature correction.  In which case you just need to read through the 418 page *.pdf and find the relationship or ..
2. It is uncalibrated and you can only get an approximation.  SO that means that you have to calibrate the input vs. binary # ahead of time and hope it does not change with temperature too much.  Simply sweep the voltage on the pin, read it with a DMM and compare that to the ADC value.

Since this is a high volume product with tight profit margins I suspect #2 is what you'll have to do.

Keep in mind that you also will have tolerances on the R18 and R19 it's looking more and more like you'll just have to calibrate it.  Of course this all depends upon precision needed.  You could possibly get away with just reading two values and fitting a straight line to those.  If \$D_1\$ is digital reading #1 corresponding to \$V_1\$ with the measured pair \$D_1\$, \$V_1\$ you simply:

\$V_x = \frac{V_2-V_1}{B_2-B_1}B_x+\frac{(V_1B_2-V_2B_1)}{B_2-B_1}\$

where \$B_x\$ is the new sample value.

Using your samples:"V1= 10V, V2= 12V; B1= 2023, B2= 2428, Bx= 2432"

We get V = \$ = \frac{2}{405}B_x + 0.0098 = 0.004938 B_x + 0.0098\$

\$V_X = 12.02 \$

Comment: RAWBRAWB: thanks for the detailed answer. I applied your idea/technique, and this what i got:
V1= 10V, V2= 12V;
B1= 2023, B2= 2428, Bx= 2432;
Vx = 16.009
Bx was taken at 12V.
This is where your foresight of calibration comes in. AM I RIGHT?

Comment: I had a typo - now fixed and I added values that gave, double check it.  You'll notice that the ADC has a slight offset but isn't too bad.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your ADC is configured, and what the reference voltage is.  Assuming the number is read directly as a N-bit integer that's justified to the LSB (i.e., the most significant bits beyond ADC resolution are zero),

$$
V_{in}= V_{ref}* \frac {ADC \ Reading}{(2^N-1)}
$$

Sure, there are nonlinearites and noise considerations, but this should be a pretty good first pass

Comment: Scott: to your equation we have to consider the gain provided by R19 and R18.
Vin=(Vref*ADC_reading*gain)/2^N
Note: i am ignoring the effect of -1. TO those large values it doesnt affect much. If i am wrong, please do correct me.

Comment: I'm giving the equation for analog voltage at the analog input pin.  That's what the adc sees, and what I thought you were asking for. If you'd like the answer to the question to say "what's the equation for the voltage at U_KL30 as a function of the voltage at UB?", then you should clarify.

Comment: In fact, you ASKED DIRECTLY for the relationship between the integer your ADC gave you and the voltage at U_KL30!

Comment: Mate i appreciate your answer. i just wanted to add that part. NO OFFENSE MEANT!!

Comment: None taken, sheetansh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but:

If the input at +UB is +12VDC, then you can ignore the capacitor and just calculate the divider voltage:

\$ 12V \cdot \dfrac{R19}{R18+R19} = 12V \cdot \dfrac{3.3k}{13.3k} = 2.98V \$

The diodes will limit the voltage range from just over 5V to just under 0V.

For the digital representation, it depends on the ADC resolution and reference voltage. For example, if you have a 10-bit ADC with a reference voltage of 5V, then the 2.98V would be:

\$ \dfrac{2.98V}{5V} \cdot 2^{10}  = 610 = 1001100010 \$